# Updating React parent (function) from it's child (class) with a twist

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

First of all, I really REALLY had read dozens of similar questions, but yet weren't able to find any working solution for my problem. Maybe the solution is not that complicated, but I'm a beginner at React, and don't have enough experience to deal with it.

I have a ManagePage.js that is a functional component and uses React Hooks for its state. And it works for rendering all devices in a table, displays An't Modal for Update/Delete, and a warning when you want to delete a device from a list (I only started to implement the ability to create/update/remove devices from a state). It looks like this:

```js
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { Layout, Input, Space, Table } from "antd";
    import ManageItem from "../components/ManageItem";

    const ManagePage = () => {

    const [devices, setDevices] = useState([
        {
          id: "some_id",
          type: "some type",
          name: "Some Name",
          value: 123,

        },
        {
          id: "some_id2",
          type: "some type2",
          name: "Some Name2",
          value: 1234,

        },
      ]);

      function removeDevice(id) {
        setDevices(devices.filter((e) => e.id !== id));
      }

      const data = devices.flatMap((device) => [
        {
          id: device.id,
          type: device.type,
          name: device.name,
          value: device.value,
          actions: (
            <ManageItem
              deviceId={device.id}
              deviceType={device.type}
              deviceName={device.name}
              deviceValue={device.value}
              onRemoveDevice={removeDevice}
            />
          ),
        },
      ]);
       return (
        <div className={"manage-container"}>
          <Layout.Content>
            <Space direction="vertical">
              <h1>Manage</h1>
              <div className={"manage-add-remove-device"}>
                {" "}
                <div className={"manage-add-new-device"}>
                  <ManageItem />
                </div>
                <Input.Search
                  className={"manage-search-device"}
                  placeholder="find device"
                  onSearch={(value) => console.log(value)}
                  enterButton
                />
              </div>
            </Space>
            <Table
              rowkey={(record) => record.id}
              columns={columns}
              dataSource={data}
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          </Layout.Content>
        </div>
      );
      };
```

As you can see I'm using [and.design](https://ant.design) (because Cube.js works on it). This is the child component:

```
    import React from "react";
    import { Input, Modal, Form, Button, Select, Tooltip } from "antd";

    class ManageItem extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.showForm = this.showForm.bind(this);
        this.showDeleteConfirm = this.showDeleteConfirm.bind(this);
      }

       state = { isFormVisible: false };

      showDeleteConfirm = () => {
        Modal.confirm({
          title: "Are you sure you want to do this?",
          icon: <ExclamationCircleOutlined />,
          content: `Device "${this.props.deviceName}" with ID "${this.props.deviceId}" will be removed from this list.`,
          onOk: onRemoveDevice(this.props.deviceId),
          onCancel() {
            console.log("Cancel");
          },
        });
      };

      showForm = () => {
        this.setState({
          isFormVisible: true,
        });
      };

      return (
          <div>
            {this.props.deviceId ? (
                <Tooltip title="remove device">
                  <a
                    onClick={this.showDeleteConfirm}
                    className={"manage-remove-device"}
                  >
                    <CloseSquareOutlined />
                  </a>
                </Tooltip>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <a onClick={this.showForm}>
                <h3>
                  <PlusSquareOutlined /> Add new device
                </h3>
              </a>
            )}
            {.........}
        );
      }
    }

    export default ManageItem;
```

All I want is to use `onOk:` in child's `showDeleteConfirm` to delete a selected device from a parent. If you have any other suggestions, how to improve my code I will be very happy to hear it!

Comment: I think in your ManageItem child componenent you should call onOk:this.props.onRemoveDevice(this.props.deviceId) bcz you already passing onRemoveDevice from parent to child i.e ManageItem

Comment: We are closer and closer to desired effect! Sadly, when onOk looks like this: `onOk: this.props.onRemoveDevice(this.props.deviceId)` it gets executed immidietly after alert shows up (before you have chance to confirm this action). When using it like function: `onOk() { this.props.onRemoveDevice(this.props.deviceId)}` I get `TypeError: this is undefined`.

I know I can bind `onOk()` somehow to use ManageItem's _this_, but how?

Comment: try this.  "   onOk:()=>{this.props.onRemoveDevice(this.props.deviceId)}    ". It will work I think..

Comment: You, sir, are my hero. Now it works like a charm :)

I was trying before to use arrow function, but in an improper way: `onOk = () =>`. Didn't think of using it this way. Thanks again!

Comment: Of course, my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your ManageItem child componenent you should call onOk like below.

```
onOk:()=>{this.props.onRemoveDevice(this.props.deviceId)}
```

bcz you already passing onRemoveDevice from parent to child i.e ManageItem

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move showDeleteConfirm function on parent, remove from child and call from child with props.function, adding "PropTypes" can you read about this: [PropTypes](https://it.reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Comment: It's an option, but I wanted to store all logic for managing one item in `ManageItem` component for maintainability reasons.